# Is our technology advanced enough to start asteroid mining?

Tags: asteroid, solar-system

[Here is a comparison of nearby asteroids](http://www.asterank.com) with their worth in US Dollars. Does our technology have the capability to reach any of these asteroids and bring back enough of the materials to be considered profitable?

Comment: Related: [What resources could be gained from asteroid mining that would be worth the effort?](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/633/what-resources-could-be-gained-from-asteroid-mining-that-would-be-worth-the-effo)

Comment: You might be interested in a book called [Mining the Sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mining_the_Sky). Also, the Wikipedia article on [Asteroid mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_mining) gives a good overview.

Comment: The real point of asteroid mining would not be to bring it back to earth, but to construct industry and craft in high orbit. Given the exorbitant costs to lift materials and fuel into orbit, even a kilogram of water ice has a functional value of around $5-10k when you take these avoided launch costs into account. In short, asteroid mining and industry has the potential to bootstrap human space exploration and expansion so greatly that it is hard to over emphasise its value.